# How to Spawn Instances on Specific Vertices?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, vertices, instances

### I am looking for an easy way to make basemeshes with interchangeable parts using Geometry Nodes.

I figured it would be interesting to use Geometry Nodes to make a random character generator: my idea is to set a base body with "anchors" that would specify where head/limbs will be instanced (eg. one for the head, other for the left arm, one for a wing etc). Each "anchor" would spawn a bodypart randomly instanced from a collection. The Geometry Nodes could also have parameters to fine tune the position, rotation and scaling of the instance.

The basic instancing is made for random and massive distribution of instances, and I'm unable to point a specific face of vertex for the instances to spawn. There is also the problem of being unable to change the body mesh to add more variety.

Is it possible to set specific vertices to spawn the meshes as I want?
I have seen users achieve similar effects with python, but I have no experience with coding.
Can someone point me the right path to solve this?

(I have added an image to describe the idea - the empties are placed to give a loose idea of the position of the "anchors")

[image: this is an attempt to describe the character generator]

Comment: If you share your project with https://blend-exchange.com/ it will be easier to help you

Comment: what version of Blender are you using?

Comment: I apologize for the delay, was out of town without access to Blender, but I'll make sure to upload the file by tomorrow at max. shmuel I am using version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

in 3.5 there is a new feature that allows you to set attribute in edit mode, so uou can have a lot finer control.

My first thought is, make a collection or a set of collections with different components that are interchangeable and use the *instances on points* "**pick instances**" functionality where you set the index of the instance you want to choose on the point (it'an integer input called *instance index*).

so what you can do with this is either use a random value (with a range of the amount of components in the collection), of setcit manuals in edit mode (using the featurei mentionedat the top).

You can use a separate *instance on points* for each set of components that you have (that are interchangeable), and you separate your points to go into them,

or you can switch between different collection based on a selection of index.

- the way the index would work is.. you'd combine all the collection to one (within geometry nodes) and then offset the index according to how may instances are in each collection its either some manual setup
- or you can auto calculate it with accumulate nodes,
- or you can get fancy and store attributes in the components themselves and have one collection (in which case you'd have to realize all the instance before you instance them and transfer the attributes back)

I'm rambling a bit now, so I'd you're interested in any of these things in specific let me know.

If you have any questions leave it in the comments of updates your question.